# MySQL Query have 2 array, but 1 of them not show result

Tags: php, mysql

I have code below

```
<?php

mysql_connect("x", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "select sp1.sale_id idsale, 
round((sik1.quantity_purchased*sik1.item_unit_price)+((IFNULL(0,sit1.percent)/100)*(sik1.quantity_purchased*sik1.item_unit_price))-
((sik1.discount_percent/100)*(sik1.quantity_purchased*sik1.item_unit_price))) as total,
round(sum(sp1.payment_amount)) as paid, DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d') as now, 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(max(sp1.payment_date),INTERVAL 20 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') as 'duedate',

if ((round((sik1.quantity_purchased*sik1.item_unit_price)+((IFNULL(0,sit1.percent)/100)*(sik1.quantity_purchased*sik1.item_unit_price))-
((sik1.discount_percent/100)*(sik1.quantity_purchased*sik1.item_unit_price))))>(round(sum(sp1.payment_amount))),0,1) as lunas,
if ((DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(max(sp1.payment_date),INTERVAL 10 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d'),DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d')))<0,0,1) due

from sales_payments sp1
left join sales_items sik1 on (sik1.sale_id=sp1.sale_id)
left join sales_items_taxes sit1 on
(sit1.sale_id=sp1.sale_id)
where sik1.quantity_purchased IS NOT NULL
group by sp1.sale_id
union
select sp2.sale_id idsale, 
round((sik2.quantity_purchased*sik2.item_kit_unit_price)+((IFNULL(0,sit2.percent)/100)*(sik2.quantity_purchased*sik2.item_kit_unit_price))-
((sik2.discount_percent/100)*(sik2.quantity_purchased*sik2.item_kit_unit_price))) as total,
round(sum(sp2.payment_amount)) as paid, DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d') as now, 
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(max(sp2.payment_date),INTERVAL 20 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') as 'duedate',

if ((round((sik2.quantity_purchased*sik2.item_kit_unit_price)+((IFNULL(0,sit2.percent)/100)*(sik2.quantity_purchased*sik2.item_kit_unit_price))-
((sik2.discount_percent/100)*(sik2.quantity_purchased*sik2.item_kit_unit_price))))>(round(sum(sp2.payment_amount))),0,1) as lunas,
if ((DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(max(sp2.payment_date),INTERVAL 10 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d'),DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d')))<0,0,1) due

from sales_payments sp2
left join sales_item_kits sik2 on (sik2.sale_id=sp2.sale_id)
left join sales_item_kits_taxes sit2 on
(sit2.sale_id=sp2.sale_id)
where sik2.quantity_purchased IS NOT NULL
group by sp2.sale_id";

/*
The result of query is

"payment_id";"sale_id";"payment_type";"payment_amount";"truncated_card";"card_issuer";"payment_date"
"84";"49";"Tunai";"150000.0000000000";;;"2015-01-11 00:01:40"
"85";"52";"Tunai";"150000.0000000000";"0";;"2015-01-11 00:18:41"
"87";"53";"Tunai";"750000.0000000000";"0";;"2015-01-11 00:24:53"
"102";"50";"Tunai";"75000.0000000000";"0";;"2014-12-16 22:45:12"
"104";"54";"Tunai";"20000.0000000000";"0";;"2015-01-12 02:36:19"
"105";"51";"Tunai";"135000.0000000000";"0";;"2015-01-13 03:04:49"

*/
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");
            $result_array = array();

            while($ngebon = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                if ($ngebon['total'] > $ngebon['paid']) { 
                    $result_array[] = $ngebon['idsale'];    
                    echo $ngebon['idsale']." ".$ngebon['due']."<br>"; //result is idsale 50 and 51
                }
            }

            $result2 = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");
            $result_array_due = array();
            while($ngebon2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            { 
                if ($ngebon2['due'] = 0) { 
                    $result_array_due[] = $ngebon2['idsale'];
                    echo $ngebon2['idsale']." ".$ngebon2['due']."<br>"; //no result
                }
            }
?>
```

My code above has 2 array but access the same query but please see the name of array is different.

What i expect is to show

```
$ngebon2['idsale'] where $ngebon2['due'] = 0 (Column 'due' is int).
```

But all i do it has no result for $ngebon2 whereas $ngebon is showed correctly. The fact is query executing in phpmyadmin show that there's 1 result

```
of$ngebon2['idsale'] where $ngebon2['due'] = 0  .
```

You can check Result of query above.

can somebody help?

Comment: If your problem concerns only mysql, then remove all no Sql code please, its hard to read it.

Comment: Hi Beri thanks for suggestion but what no sql code u mean? because the array code seems important to know....

Comment: Sorry, our tag misled me - your query returns results, according to your comment, so add PHP tag to your question. The problem must be there then,

Comment: ok thanks for adding PHP tag to my question..